# ¿Cómo utilizar py2exe para distintas versiones de Windows?

Tags: python

Tengo claro cómo hacer un exe y resulta muy bien si lo hago en windows 7 y lo ejecuto en windows 7 y lo mismo en W8 pero no he logrado hacer un exce que me funcione en ambos.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['hello.py'])
```

Lo que necesito es poder hacer un exe que se pueda ejecutar en windows independiente de su versión. ¿Alguien sabe cómo hacer esto?

Comment: También puedes probar pyinstaller, que está más mantenido ahora y es multiplataforma http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Answer (score 1):

*py2exe* se limita a juntar en un único ejecutable todos los ficheros que necesita tu programa python para funcionar. Para abarcar varias versiones de windows necesitarás crear un *instalador* que instale la versión apropiada al sistema objetivo. Para python, es muy común utilizar el instalador ["Inno Setup"](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/innosetup).

Comment: Luego de usar py2exe hago el instalador con Inno Setup pero el problema sigue siendo el mismo. Entonces la pregunta cambia a ¿Cómo crear un instalador que instale el ejecutable en varias versiones de windows? al menos en las 3 últimas 7, 8 y 10

Comment: OK, aunque sería mejor que editaras la pregunta inicial para que quede clara. Te vas a encontrar con dos problemas: las versiones 32 bits/64 bits, y los problemas de permisos para modificar el registro de windows y ficheros de configuración. Espero que puedan darte una respuesta alguien con más experiencia con las versiones de windows que usas.